Is there a spurious correlation between slope and intercept of a simple linear regression under constrained x and y?
I am trying to determine if I can use the y-intercept of a simple linear regression to predict the slope but I want to confirm whether the y-intercept is spuriously correlated with the slope. Would this occur when the x values and y values can only be between a certain range? I found an earlier post that mentioned "in simple linear regression, the correlation between the estimated slope and intercept has the opposite sign of the mean of the explanatory variables. I.e., if the mean of the explanatory variables is positive, the correlation between the estimated coefficients will be negative and vice versa.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Unless the explanatory data are centered at 0, there is always a non-zero correlation between the least squares estimates of intercept and slope, regardless of the ranges of the data.  Could you perhaps explain what application you have in mind where you would have only the estimated intercept but not the estimated slope?

You will want to distinguish between (intercept, slope) qua parameter of the model, which you appear to consider random variables, and their estimates.  Do you have data that permit you to do that, such as repeated experiments with collections of $(x,y)$ observations?

Somewhat related: Correlation between OLS estimators for intercept and slope.

@whuber I have repeated collections of observational data for many (300+) food web variables necessary to make TMS (d15N and contaminant concentration in each organism). I'm not sure if this data permits me to do that

Whether those data are useful for this purpose depends on your experimental design and your model for the data.  It would help us to know some of those details.

That is an interesting question!  It's complicated by the fact that the degree of correlation between the estimates depends on the details of each dataset, especially on the mean and variance of the explanatory variable.  Do you have information about how those quantities differ among the datasets?

The explanatory variable supplies the values used as "x" in the regression.
